# Is there a zero-argument Predicate?

Tags: java, java-8

Is there a default interface used as zero argument `Predicate`, which essentially is a `Supplier<Boolean>`, which, again, essentially is:

```
public interface Condition {
  boolean test();
}
```

If there isn't (I can't seem to find one), then why would it be absent? Isn't it really useful?

Comment: Where would you expect to use this?

Comment: What's wrong with `Supplier<Boolean>` or its primitive counterpart, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BooleanSupplier.html ?

Comment: @JonSkeet For example, as a custom stopping condition for some algorithm.

Comment: @Marco13 Mostly semantics (`Supplier` is supposed to supply something outcoming, not test something external). But I guess `BooleanSupplier` is fine for me, didn't notice it, to be honest.

Answer (score 3):

The only scenario I could see for it would be a function that uses global state to decide on return value.

In that case it's a abuse of that interface. However instead you may pass that global variable as a parameter and all will be working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The only 'Zero' argument predicate that would make sense would be constants (true|false). As the set of possible implementations is, by definition, limited to 2 why would you complicate (or dream of) an interface for 2 constant conditions?

Imagine the silliness of this code:

```
if() {
   doFoo();
}
```

**If what, then doFoo()?!** It can only be *true* or the code can be removed. And if it's a constant of *true* then the predicate is pointless.

Comment: The set of all possible implementations is not limited to 2, if we anonymously instantiate that interface, it can access other variables in the context it was instantiated.

Comment: A predicate may produce 'true' or it may produce 'false'. It doesn't matter WHAT you base it on. The result domain is of cardinality size 2. I think you want to base your predicate on a variable outside of the predicate call context. That you can certainly do.

Comment: An interface like this could still make sense, if the cost of figuring out true/false is high. Consider a case where you want to possibly look up a book. In some earlier phase, you compiled a list of conditions: if the book is known locally, if it's in a database, if Amazon knows about it, etc. Later on, you want to actually compute the final answer, but you want to look at each predicate in turn, so that you don't have to do the expensive ones of he cheap ones give you the answer. You can imagine how this could make sense in some cases.